# Can you query the YouTube API v3 with Python Requests alone?

Tags: python, youtube-api, python-requests, youtube-data-api

It seems that v2 was created quite a long time ago so I'm focusing on getting my needs met with v3. The Python code examples for v3 are all [very long](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python) and although I have created a project in my Google account and an API key, downloaded `client_secrets.json` :

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "********",
    "project_id": "my-project",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "***********",
    "redirect_uris": [
      "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob",
      "http://localhost"
    ]
  }
}
```

have so far not made much progress with the code samples.

So am testing something simpler, just to get the [Python Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to pull this request -

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories
```

found in the official v3 documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list).

Am using the following code with elements from the json above:

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories", auth=(client_id, client_secret))
r.status_code
```

This is returning 403 (Forbidden) so can't move forward at this stage. Does anyone know how to get this to work and if it is even possible?

Comment: You're setting yourself up for pain by choosing to build a client in requests yourself, instead of using the code and high quality examples provided by YouTube themselves.

Comment: Will get back to the official Python binding soon if this doesn't deliver. I think the code above has not worked because the API v3 needs OAuth2, have been testing out some code with the library `oauthlib.oauth2` but it's just not working yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`403 (Forbidden)`  means that you don't have access to do what you are trying to do.   You should check the full error message you are getting from the server there is normally more then just that.

[videoCategories.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list) is a public method get an API key from the Google Developer Console and just tack it on the end

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?key=yourkey

Using the official [Google python client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) will make your life a lot easer.  Once you start working with methods that require Oauth2 you don't want to have to code that yourself if you can avoid it.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got your link to work, it initially returned a small piece of JSON asking for more but once `&part=snippet&regionCode=de` was tacked onto the end of it, it was happy and returned a lot of JSON full of categories and other information, both in a browser and with `requests.get()`. Alright, after the struggle with `oauthlib.oauth2` yesterday and your warning, will focus on understanding and using the existing library, something about that oauth2 and its tokens seems **not** straightforward. _public_ method also something was good to learn.

Comment: Learning Oauth2 is not strait forward.   Its doable but if you want to avoid some gray hair just use the client library.   Top tip: don't bother with service accounts they don't work with YouTube API.   The YouTube API is channel based if you have more then one channel you will need to authenticate to each of them.

Comment: Will see how far I get with it - am not using it to look at my own channel(s) but for general data mining. Once am passed the hurdle of accessing it at all, remains to be seen how much it is going to allow that.

Comment: If your just data mining then just use the API key as long as its public data you don't need OAuth2.   This might help http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-create-public-api-key/

Comment: Thanks had a look at http://www.daimto.com/open-authentication/ now aware of the 3 kinds of authentication they use. The first (API key) will probably suffice as you say, and the short answer to the original question is probably "yes, can do quite a bit effectively with requests alone".